I want to create a cyclic shape in its simplest form


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[](A){A};
\node[right of=A](B){B};
\node[right of=B](C){C};
\path[draw, -latex'] (A) -- node[above]{$text$} (B);
\path[draw, -latex'] (B) -- node[above]{$text$} (C);
\path[draw, -latex'] (A) to [bend right]  node[below]{text} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I tried with this code but I cannot change the direction of the arrow at the bottom

Welcome to TeX.SE! You've tagged this as tikz-pgf, which implies that you've heard of tikz already. I would recommend starting with the tutorials, and then coming here if you gt stuck on a specific problem. This site isn't really meant to a human-powered image-to-tikz conversion tool.

Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try? What is your problem? You added the tikz-pgf tag, so you probably should know about the online manual of this package that contains nice tutorials and examples. Please help us help you and tell us more about your issue. This site is not meant to be a free human-powered scribbles-to-TikZ conversion tool.

@Jasper How did you know what I was about to write =D

@JasperHabicht Haha, what a coincidence! They're like the same comment

Instead of writing the code using inline formatting, could you use a code block by highlighting it and pressing the {} button? Also, you should always post a minimal working example that we can copy and paste to reproduce the error, not just the code for the tikzpicture. For example, a minimal working example loads all the packages and has a begin and end document. Thank you!

instead of -latex for the arrow, use latex- if you want to reverse the direction. better yet, load arrows.meta and use Latex-.

Thank you for all, I am learning to use the site with your help.

Thank you for posting a MWE!
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\newcommand{\mytext}{\{\textbackslash text\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(A){A};
\node[right=2cm of A](B){B};
\node[right=2cm of B](C){C};
\draw[->] (A) -- node[above]{\mytext} (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- node[above]{\mytext} (C);
\draw[->] (C) to [bend left] node[below]{\mytext} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much for your concern and help.
